# How To Count Rows But Based On Another Column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| Username     | Message                     | Status         |
+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| jamesbond    | I need some help            | SendingOK      |
| jamesbond    | I need some help            | SendingOK      |
| jamesbond    | I need some help            | SendingFailed  |
| jamesbond    | Mission accomplished        | SendingOK      |
+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

produced by this SQL syntax :

```
SELECT A.Username, A.Message, B.Status
FROM db1.SmsBroadcast as A
INNER JOIN db2.sentitems as B 
ON A.MessageSMS1 = B.TextDecoded
WHERE A.Username = 'jamesbond'
GROUP BY Message, Status
```

now how to have this output?

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Username     | Message                     | SendingOK | SendingFailed |
+--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| jamesbond    | I need some help            | 2         | 1             |
| jamesbond    | Mission accomplished        | 1         | 0             |
+--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

`SendingOK` and `SendingFailed` column is actually can be calculated using `COUNT(*)`, but I have no idea how to count based on same Message, while those message is executed in same SQL syntax. any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `CASE` in your `SELECT` statement and GROUPED them by `username` and `message`.

```
SELECT `UserName`, 
        `Message`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'SendingOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OkStat,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'SendingFailed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FailedStat
FROM    db1.SmsBroadcast as A
        JOIN db2.sentitems as B 
            ON A.MessageSMS1 = B.TextDecoded
WHERE   A.Username = 'jamesbond'
GROUP BY A.Username, A.Message
```

Comment: it's you again John... and your solution is very helpful!! +1 and accept as an answer... as usual... ;-)

Comment: you forgot to add 'AS' before OkStat and FailedStat

Comment: @RobertHanson `AS` is optional :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Username, A.Message,
   SUM(CASE WHEN B.Status = 'SendingOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SendingOK ,
   SUM(CASE WHEN B.Status = 'SendingFailed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SendingFailed,
FROM db1.SmsBroadcast as A
INNER JOIN db2.sentitems as B ON A.MessageSMS1 = B.TextDecoded
WHERE A.Username = 'jamesbond'
GROUP BY A.Username, A.Message
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known number of values to turn into columns, then you can hard-code them similar to the other answers. But if you have an unknown number, then you can use [prepared statements](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when Status = ''',
      Status,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ',
      Status
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM db2.sentitems;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT A.Username, A.Message, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM db1.SmsBroadcast A
                  INNER JOIN db2.sentitems B 
                    ON A.MessageSMS1 = B.TextDecoded
                  WHERE A.Username = ''jamesbond''
                  GROUP BY A.Username, A.Message');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The main difference with this is that it generates the SQL string based on the values in your `db2.sentitems` so if the values change, then this will automatically adjust without having to alter your code.